# Symfony2 JMSSerializer replace inline text

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

I'm looking for a simple, stupid solution, to change the output of serialized fields to **replace several patterns** (for user messages etc) in [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2).

Unfortunately, the usage of [Custom De-/Serialization Handlers](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/cookbook/custom_handlers) destroys all my policies. I'm forced to return all serialized data by hand.

The Model class:

```
//src/Acme/DemoBundle/Model/Tiger

class Tiger implements WildAnimalInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Expose
     * @Type('user_message')
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $dangerLevel;

    ...
}
```

The Handler class:

```
class UserMessageHandler 
{  
    ...

    public function serialize(VisitorInterface $visitor, 
                              WildAnimalInterface $wildAnimal, 
                              $type, 
                              $visited)  
    {  
        // Hello {{username}}, I'm a Tiger ROOARRR!
        $text = $wildAnimal->getText(); 

        // (my custom replacement logic, it works already)

        // Hello Joe Schmoe, I'm a Tiger ROOARRR!
        return $text;  // < Overwrites all rules and returns only text!
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you exactly mean, but can't you use the @postserialize and @postdeserialize (http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#postserialize) annotations?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found the solution, I explain it here : [Format input and output fields with JMSSerializer (handle single property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687489/format-input-and-output-fields-with-jmsserializer-handle-single-property)